# UIImagePickerController delegate not called Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, swift3

On the surface I thought that this had to be a delegate issue, but after asking for the delegate the right one was returned.

I created an ImagePicker class to handle all the UIImagePickerController stuff. Every thing works until the delegate methods need to be called. After I pick a photo, the imagePicker dismisses, but the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method never gets called. Please help! Thanks :)

```
func selectPhoto() {
    imagePicker.delegate = self //Delegate gets set here

    let photoAsk = UIAlertController.init( //Ask user if they want to take picture or choose one
        title: "Edit Profile Picture",
        message: nil,
        preferredStyle: .alert)
    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction.init(
        title: "Take Photo",
        style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
            if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)) {
                self.imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
                UIApplication.topViewController()!.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion:nil)
            } else {
                print("Cannot access camera in simulator.")
                return
            }
    }
    let photoLibraryAction = UIAlertAction.init(
        title: "Photo Library",
        style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            UIApplication.topViewController()!.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion:nil)
            print("UIImagePickerDelegate: \(self.imagePicker.delegate.debugDescription)") // <--THIS PRINTS OUT "AppName.ImagePicker: 0x145d7bdf0>", and the class name is ImagePicker
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction.init(
        title: "Cancel",
        style: .cancel) { (UIAlertAction) in return }

    photoAsk.addAction(cameraAction)
    photoAsk.addAction(photoLibraryAction)
    photoAsk.addAction(cancelAction)

    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]

    UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(photoAsk, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This never gets called:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    print("Image picked.") //NEVER PRINTS
}
```

Comment: Try to set `imagePicker.delegate = self`in `viewDidLoad`instead

Comment: @RashwanL It's a custom class, but I tried putting it in the class's `init` method and there's no difference.

Comment: I'm confused. Where is `selectPhoto()` being called?

Comment: Is there a strong reference anywhere to the instance of this custom class posted in your question?

Comment: @Aaron - `selectPhoto()` is being called from a `UIViewController`. That view controller has a circular `UIImageView` with a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on top. When tapped, it creates an instance of `ImageHelper` and calls the method. Sorry for not including that.

Comment: @ClaytonAndrewCohn Did you got any solution? I am facing the same issue with ImageHelper class.

Answer (score 22):

I had to copy the method names straight from the delegate. For some reason the auto-complete has the method headers wrong.

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        //save image
        //display image
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**UPDATE SWIFT 5:**

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        //save image
        //display image
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You are the best! I was trying too hard to figure out the issue but the delegate wasn't simply being called. Reason :: method name was slightly different : 
What I had earlier :: 
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

What works : 
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

Unfortunately, the delegates are optional so if you have a slight mistake in method, you would never be able to debug why its not working.

Comment: They seem to have changed the method in Swift 5. Brutal.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me. They changed the method names but did not mentioned that old ones are deprecated, good job Apple.

Answer (score 16):

### Details

- Xcode 9.2, Swift 4
- Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001), Swift 5

### Solution

```
extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        print("\(info)")
        if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            imageView?.image = image
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = false
imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
imagePickerController.delegate = self
present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

### Full sample

> Do not forget to add **the solution code here (look above)**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private weak var imageView: UIImageView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let stackView = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        self.imageView = imageView

        let button = UIButton(frame: .zero)
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showImages), for: .touchUpInside)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
    }

    @IBAction func showImages(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = false
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post a whole bunch of code. A good answer explains what was wrong in the OP's code and how their answer solves the problem.

Comment: Ok. But in this question we have lot's of moments to explain. My English is not perfect, so, I decided to create full sample. Next time, I will try your suggest. Thank you!

Comment: Also, @VasilyBodnarchuk, I know that placing the delegate and its methods inside of my calling view controller will work. What I am trying to do is create a helper class to act as the delegate because I have 3-4 different view controllers that need to use the exact same code, and I'd rather not repeat the same two delegate calls each time I switch view controllers.

Comment: This still does not subclass the UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerDelegate. What I want to do is make a single subclass, extension or file to refer to that can handle the call regardless of the view controller I'm calling it from

Answer (score 7):

I also faced this issue and solved it by using below solution. Set picker's delegate after present completion.

```
controller.present(picker, animated: true, completion: {
            self.picker.delegate = self
        })
```

Hope this will work for you!!

Comment: Thank you, setting the delegate after present works!!!!

Answer (score 7):

As per my experience, it is an issue of ARC.

> If we define instance as locally then ARC will remove its reference
> automatically once methods scope end. If you define globally then it
> is kept in memory until the view controller is not deinitialized.

## Short Answer:

> Define `UIImagePickerController` instance globally.

## Long Answer:

I have created once the common class of `NSObject` and `delegates` method of `UIImagePickerController` is not called.

After 5 hours of brainstorming, Finally, get the solution. It seems like an issue related to **memory deallocation** during the captured image from the camera.

```
public typealias CameraBlock = (UIImage?, Bool) -> Void

class HSCameraSingleton: NSObject {
    
    var pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    private var completionBlock: CameraBlock!
    var presentationController: UIViewController?
    
    public init(presentationController: UIViewController) {
        super.init()
        self.presentationController = presentationController
    }
    
    
    public func present(completionBlock: @escaping CameraBlock) {
        guard UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) else {
            return
        }
        
        self.pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        self.pickerController.delegate = self
        self.pickerController.allowsEditing = true
        self.pickerController.sourceType = .camera
        self.completionBlock = completionBlock
        self.presentationController?.present(self.pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


extension HSCameraSingleton: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.completionBlock?(nil,false)
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
            self.completionBlock?(nil,false)
            return
        }
        self.completionBlock?(image,true)
        pickerController.dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
    }
}


class AuthViewController: UIViewController{

lazy var overlay = HSCameraSingleton(presentationController:self)

@IBAction func actionLoginTap(_ sender: UIControl) {
        
        overlay.present { (image, status) in
            print(image,status)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I found that the delegate code had to be within an active UIViewController.

I originally tried to have my code in a separate file, as as NSObject with the correct delegate protocols declared, like this:

```
class PhotoPicker: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
```

But that never called the delegate methods.

Taking the *exact* same code and placing it within the UIViewController I was calling it from made it work.

It looks like the best solution is to create a pop-up type view, and have its ViewController keep the code.

Comment: Just define PhotoPicker globally for your viewcontroller. Everythings worked as expected!

Comment: @IMHiteshSurani great answere, its working too .can you explain if why declaring globally and locally have such an effect

Comment: @HarshThakur Added details description here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59930383/5036586

Answer (score 5):

Yo have to make sure that UIImagePickerController was not released before delegate called.

> I created an ImagePicker class to handle all the
>   UIImagePickerController stuff.

I created similar class, but

```
func onButtonDidTap(sender: UIButton) {
.....
    let picker = VLImagePickerController()
    picker.show(fromSender: sender, handler: { (image: UIImage?) -> (Void) in
        if (image != nil) {
            self.setImage(image!)
        }
    })
....
}
```

did not work for me.
'picker' was released before 'handler' could be called.

I created permanent reference, and it worked:

```
let picker = VLImagePickerController()

    func onButtonDidTap(sender: UIButton) {
    .....
            //let picker = VLImagePickerController()
            picker.show(fromSender: sender, handler: { (image: UIImage?) -> (Void) in
                if (image != nil) {
                    self.setImage(image!)
                }
            })
    ....
        }
```

Comment: This happened for me...dont keep imagepicker as weak or an instance variable in a function...its best to be added as a property

Answer (score 4):

swift 4.2

Add Delegate method according ViewController

UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate

```
//IBOutlet
@IBOutlet weak var ImagePhoto: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

//Button Action Take Photo
@IBAction func btnPhotoTap(_ sender: Any) {
   
           let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
           imagePicker.delegate = self
           imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary // Or .camera as you require
           imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
           self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//MARK:-imagePickerControllerDelegate
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
           let image1 =  info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage
           self.ImagePhoto.image = image1
           self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
   
           print("Cancel")
           self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works, (although, it redisplays over and over because it displays the picker in viewWillAppear, this is just to keep code small). I would look at what is different from this. It could have to do with your top view controller? Why not just display the picker from a view controller rather than go to application's top view controller? Also, once you get the delegate callback, you need to dismiss the view controller.

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
        imagePicker.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) { // keeps reopening, do not this in your code. 
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I voted this one up because I was missing the `UINavgationControllerDelegate` declaration and this comment helped.

`imagePickerController` wasn't being called.

Answer (score 1):

Something I found that helped me was making sure the delegate was set as `public` rather than `private`.

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
```