# didFinishPickingImage does not get triggered

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a class

```
class ActivitiesMainPageController: UICollectionViewController      ,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    switch indexPath.item {

    case 0 :
        let takePictureInstance = takePictures()
        takePictureInstance.presentCamera()
    }

}
```

The takePictures() is s custom class

```
class takePictures: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate
{
   var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController! = UIImagePickerController()
  func presentCamera()
    {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera)
    {

        let objViewController =  UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController

        imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        objViewController?.present(imagePicker,animated: true,completion: nil)
   }
    else
    {
        // error msg
        print ("error displaying Camera")
         noCamera()
    }
}



  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    print(self.Tag + "image picker controller")

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

The didfinishpickingimage never gets triggered. I don't see the print statement. After reading the SO h[ere,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682915/uiimagepickercontroller-delegate-not-called-swift-3) I think I am not doing the delegate correctly. Can you please help?

Comment: The method is deprecated. That's why maybe it's not called. Could you use `optional func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])` instead?

Comment: Changed the method to didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo. Still the fuction does not get triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `ActivitiesMainPageController` class. It's a memory management issue. You create a local instance of your `takePictures` class (FYI - class names should start with uppercase letters), and then call the `presentCamera` method. And then the `takePictureInstance` variable immediately goes out of scope. This means it has no more references and it gets deallocated.

So at this point, the image picker's (weak) delegate becomes `nil`. This is why the image picker delegate method is never called.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Keep a strong reference to the `takePictures` instance inside your `ActivitiesMainPageController` class (use a property instead of a local variable). But this has the problem of not knowing when to release the instance.
2. Perform a little trick inside the `takePictures` class where it keeps a strong reference to itself when created, and then releases that strong reference after the image picker is dismissed.

Option 2 can be implemented like this:

```
class takePictures: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate
{
    var strongSelf: takePictures?
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController! = UIImagePickerController()

    func presentCamera()
    {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera)
        {
            let objViewController =  UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController

            imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
            objViewController?.present(imagePicker,animated: true,completion: nil)
            strongSelf = self // keep me around
        }
        else
        {
            // error msg
            print ("error displaying Camera")
            noCamera()
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
        print(self.Tag + "image picker controller")

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        strongSelf = nil // let me go
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you presenting the UIImagePicker from the `takePictures` class (Should be `TakePictures`)? I think the problem is originating because the view controller you're currently in is not the one presenting the picker. If you pulled that `presentCamera()` function out and put it in the `ActivitiesMainPageController`and assigned <- that as the delegate and also switched the method signature to the correct one:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
```

You should have better luck.